# Edit Makefile line: CFLAGS from Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, undefined-reference, cflags

I'm quite new to programming but I got really stuck with this so I hope you can help me.

I got a problem using the openssl/hmac.h

the Error Output:

> undefined reference to EVP_sha1

So I googled and found something:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131726

It's the exact same Problem as mine... this might be really stupid but I just don't know how to change the Line in the Makefile with the CFLAGS to the ones shown in the link :(

Just can't edit it via the makefile cause `Qt` will overwrite everything and I just don't figure out an other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using qmake here.

Yes, to avoid Makefile corruption, the Makefile itself calls again the qmake...

But you have two variables you can edit for your purposes in your `.pro` file:  `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` and `QMAKE_CFLAGS`.

[HERE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-cxxflags) you can find the qmake reference